# Solve the complex equations

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have a question from complex calculus. How to solve this two equations: 
a)
$$
\sin(z)=2015
$$
I know that $\sin(z)$ equals to 
$$
\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}
$$
And i don't know whats next.

b)
$$
e^{z^{2}}=1
$$
I know that
$$
e^{z}=e^{x}(\cos(y)+i\sin(y))
$$
Can you help me to solve this equations?

Comment: You turn your equation into a quadratic in $e^{iz}$.

Comment: If you want to check: It gives nothing nice: You find $\mathrm e^{\mathrm iz} = 2015 \mathrm {i} + 24 \mathrm i \sqrt{7049}$...

Comment: I came up in b) example that 1=e^2k(pi)i and the rest is easy.

Comment: ok. I did a) equation like you said. the answer looks terrible but i think it can be correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sin z = \sin(x + iy) = \sin x \cos (iy) + \cos x\sin(iy) = \sin x \cosh y + i\cos x\sinh y$$
$$\Rightarrow \left\{\begin{array}{l} \sin x \cosh y = 2015 \\ \cos x \sinh y = 0\end{array} \right.$$

For the second equation to be true, either $y = 0$ or $x = \displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2} + n\pi$.

$y = 0$ gives $\sin x = 2015$ which has no solution, so $\displaystyle x = \frac{\pi}{2} + n\pi$

Since $\cosh y > 0$, we expect $\sin x > 0$, so $n$ has to be an even number

Thus $\displaystyle x = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi$. This gives $\cosh y = 2015$ or $y = \cosh^{-1} (2015)$

Answer (score 0):

$$sin(z)=2015 <=> z=sin^{-1}(2015)=\frac{\pi}{2}-i*ln(2014+24\sqrt{7049})$$

It gives us (for Z is the set of integers, n element of Z):

$$z=2\pi n+\pi-sin^{-1}(2015)=2\pi n+\pi-(\frac{\pi}{2}-i*ln(2014+24\sqrt{7049}))$$

Or:

$$z=2\pi n+\pi+sin^{-1}(2015)=2\pi n+\pi+(\frac{\pi}{2}-i*ln(2014+24\sqrt{7049}))$$

And:

$$(e^z)^2=1$$

Integer solution is:

$$z=0$$

It gives us (for Z is the set of integers, n element of Z):

$$z=\sqrt{2\pi}(-\sqrt{i*n})$$
Or:
$$z=\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{i*n}$$